# How do I put a face on top of this halftone shader?

Tags: texturing, rigging, shaders, uv-image-editor

As the title says, I've been trying to put a simple black line on this half-tone shader using mix shader, mix, diffuse, etc. I've been using blender for a few months so I'm at a loss. Linked is what I want to do and my .blend.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the material called *Halftone Pixel* you need to plug your current setup into the input B of a *Color > Mix Color*, plug your image in the factor, and in input A choose the color of the drawing. Plug the *Mix Color* into an *Emission* that you plug into the *Output*:

[image]

Comment: thank you again moonboots